# HDHomeRun device connected directly to ethernet port on computer but accessible through router

Tags: networking

Ideally I'd like to connect my HDHomeRun device directly to my desktop computer's ethernet port, but if possible I'd also like the HDHomeRun device to be accessible from other computers on my router's network. My desktop computer is connected to the router (and internet) through it's WIFI adapter. I'm not sure if this is a realistic goal but I thought I'd ask. Would bridging the network connections be appropriate here? (I tried but didn't it didn't work correctly for me) - I could connect to the internet through the bridged connection but couldn't communicate with or otherwise detect the HDHomeRun.  The bridged connection had an IP address of 192.168.1.250 and my router's IP is 192.168.1.254 so they were in the same range?  (I bridged using Windows OS built in functionality, just selected both the WIFI and the Ethernet adapter at the same time, right clicked, and clicked "bridge connections")

Here is a troubleshooting document for the HDHomeRun that may be helpful if you are unfamiliar with it: http://www.silicondust.com/hdhomerun/hdhomerun_troubleshooting.pdf.  In order to have a fixed IP address the HDHomeRun's MAC address must be reserved using DHCP. If you don't use a DHCP then the HDHomeRun will assign itself a random IP address in the 169.254.x.x block. I'd like a static IP address if possible. A crossover cable is not required to connect directly to the ethernet port. Also I believe The HDHomeRun software makes use of uPnP discovery to detect the device.

My desktop is running Windows 8.

Thanks!

EDIT:

DHCP Details:

```
Device IPv4 Address 192.168.1.254
DHCPv4 Netmask  255.255.255.0
DHCPv4 Start Address    192.168.1.64
DHCPv4 End Address  192.168.1.253
DHCP Leases Available   150
DHCP Leases Allocated   40
DHCP Primary Pool   Private
```

Comment: *"In order to assign a static IP address the HDHomeRun must be make use of DHCP."* -- Perhaps what you mean is, using the MAC address of the HDHR, you should assign a [reserved or fixed IP address](http://lifehacker.com/5822605/how-to-set-up-dhcp-reservations-so-you-never-have-to-check-an-ip-address-again)  using DHCP? *"Would bridging the network connections be appropriate here? (I tried but didn't it didn't work correctly for me)"* -- Yes, so you had better investigate why that *"didn't work"*.  Perhaps you created a distinct subnet (and that isn't accessible by the wireless router)?

Comment: Yes, you interpreted correctly, I mean " using the MAC address of the HDHR, you should assign a reserved or fixed IP address using DHCP?"

My router's ip address is 192.168.1.254.  The bridged connection had an ip address of 192.168.1.247.  I could connect to the internet fine with this setup.  It's just that I couldn't seem to communicate with the HDHomeRun and the HDHomeRun software couldn't detect it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the IP addresses (and how they are assigned) of the LAN side of the wireless router, the wireless port of the PC, the wired Ethernet of the PC and the HDHR.  Describe the DHCP server's configuration: what is the range of the dynamic address pool? What are the reserved addresses?   Did you reset/reboot everything after configuration?

Comment: Edited my question to try to include the information as best I can.  I'm not sure how to get IP addresses of the individual adapters after bridging so I did ipconfig /all hope that helps.  Also I'm not sure how to get the IP address of the HDHomeRun - I didn't see it's MAC address listed in my router's device list.  I hadn't actually reserved an address for it's MAC address yet - hadn't got that far.  Also I rebooted the HDHomerun and the computer but didn't think of rebooting router or anything else.  I can try and see if it helps

Comment: *" I hadn't actually reserved an address for it's MAC address yet - hadn't got that far."* -- Then your assessment of it *"didn't work"* and your first response/comment are **grossly misleading**.  Get a patch cable and temporarily connect the HDHR (no antenna/cableTV RF connection necessary) to a LAN port on the wireless router to get its MAC address.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think anything was misleading. My assumption is that it should still work without reserving a specific IP by MAC address, it's just that I'll get whatever IP address the router wants to assign it rather than a fixed one?  Wanted to let you know that I think it's all working now, restarting everything including the router seemed to help.  I can connect to the HDHomerun now with the bridged connection!